# How to capture encoded video frames on WP Mango?

Tags: video, video-encoding, windows-phone-7

To send those frame to network, for instance. I know, that CaptureSource and VideoSink can give you access to video frames, but are they encoded already? And if not, can I use hardware accelerated encoding ( which is required by MS for all the WP7 device vendors ) somehow?

Answer (score 1):

They are not encoded, Capture Source and VideoSink output frames in ARGB format as an array of  int (or bytes I don't remember). About the hardware accelerated encoding, I'm not sure.